# Can anybody explain composition ( java ) in simple language with example

Tags: java, composition

I have recently started learning java. When it comes to composition I am super confused, cannot seem to find explanation which is written with simple examples. If somebody can explain with simple examples would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Google this : "composition java" and/or search here on SO .

Answer (score 1):

> **Composition** is a special case of aggregation. In a more specific
>   manner, a restricted aggregation is called composition. When an object
>   contains the other object, if the contained object cannot exist
>   without the existence of container object, then it is called
>   composition.
>
> **Example 1**: A class contains students. A student cannot exist without a
>   class. There exists composition between class and students.
>
> **Example 2**: A Library contains students and books. Relationship between
>   library and student is aggregation. Relationship between library and
>   book is composition. A student can exist without a library and
>   therefore it is aggregation. A book cannot exist without a library and
>   therefore its a composition.

Answer (score 0):

To use composition in Java, you use instance variables of one object to hold references to other objects.

For example :

```
class CoffeeCup {

    private Coffee innerCoffee;

    public void addCoffee(Coffee newCoffee) {
        // no implementation yet
    }

    public Coffee releaseOneSip(int sipSize) {
        // no implementation yet
        // (need a return so it will compile)
        return null;
    }

    public Coffee spillEntireContents() {
        // no implementation yet
        // (need a return so it will compile)
        return null;
    }
}

public class Coffee {

    private int mlCoffee;

    public void add(int amount) {
        // No implementation yet
    }

    public int remove(int amount) {
        // No implementation yet
        // (return 0 so it will compile)
        return 0;
    }

    public int removeAll() {
        // No implementation yet
        // (return 0 so it will compile)
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Taken from [here](http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/CompoInherit1.html)  .